# Converting nsstring to macro (#define)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I receive from from the server the following JSON:

```
{
   .....
   "id":"predifined_id",
   ...
}
```

In the code I have an int definition for the predifined_id:

```
#define predifined_id   5
```

Which means that if I use predifined_id in code it will be translated to int = 5.

How can I fetch this value (5) when I am parsing the JSON?

I have converted the JSON to `NSDictionary`, but the value that I receive for @"id" key, is `NSString`

Comment: Why don't you just `#define predefined_id @"5"` ?

Comment: the macros for _compiler time_ only, you cannot deal with them during _runtime_ – they just don't exist in runtime.

Comment: @l0gg3r, totally different question

Comment: @Paulw11, predefined_id will still not be recognised as macro when parsing the JSON. It only be a NSString

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. All #define does is cause the compiler to make a substitution when you compile the program.   Do you want to convert the string value from the dictionary to an int?  If so, then @mityaika07 is correct

Comment: @Paulw11 No, I want to convert the string value from the dictionary to the macro

Comment: You can't convert a string to a macro. A macro is just a compile-time text substitution

Answer (score 1):

in my code I use this:

```
NSInteger integerValue = [dict[@"id"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define it as string

```
#define predifined_id  @"5"
```

or convert it later:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",predefined_id]
```